# problem showing Variables undefined not showing

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementbyid

1.My Code is getting all the prices and output it on the DOM,compute it by getting the subtotal of textprice,calcprice,backprice, and Get it out from the global 
scope.

2.It has sales tax of 13%

3.The code should Use `getelementbyID` and `textContent`.

4.Keep all the variables from global scope

5.My Problem is the `textPrice` is `undefined`?

````
   //Variables
   function getInput(){
       let items = ['textPrice', 'calcPrice', 'backPrice'] ;
       return items;
   }


   function getBackPrice(){
       let backElement = document.getElementById("back-price") ;
       let backPrice= document.getElementById("back-price").textContent;
       return backPrice;
   }


   function getCalcPrice(){
       let calcElement = document.getElementById("calc-price") ;
       let calcPrice= document.getElementById("calc-price").textContent;
       return calcPrice;
   }

   function getTextPrice(){
       let textElement = document.getElementById("text-price") ;
       let textPrice= document.getElementById("text-price").textContent;
       return textPrice;
   }

   //Get Subtotal
   function getsubTotal(){
       let subTotal = parseFloat(textPrice) + parseFloat(calcPrice) + parseFloat(backPrice);
       return subTotal;

   }

   getsubTotal(); ```
````

Comment: could you please share your html part as well?

Comment: what i did is i called the function name, instead of the variable name. -case closed

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getInput(){
       let items = ['textPrice', 'calcPrice', 'backPrice'] ;
       return items;
   }


   function getBackPrice(){
       let backElement = document.getElementById("back-price") ;
       let backPrice= document.getElementById("back-price").textContent;
       return backPrice;
   }


   function getCalcPrice(){
       let calcElement = document.getElementById("calc-price") ;
       let calcPrice= document.getElementById("calc-price").textContent;
       return calcPrice;
   }

   function getTextPrice(){
       let textElement = document.getElementById("text-price") ;
       let textPrice= document.getElementById("text-price").textContent;
       return textPrice;
   }

   //Get Subtotal
   function getsubTotal(){
      var textPrice= $("#text-price").text();
      var calcPrice= $("#calc-price").text();
      var backPrice= $("#back-price").text();

      let subTotal = parseFloat(textPrice) + parseFloat(calcPrice) + parseFloat(backPrice);
      $("#sub-total").text(subTotal.toFixed(2));
      return subTotal;
   }

   getsubTotal();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="">
            <h2>Purchased Items</h2>
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
                    <th class="quantity" scope="col">Item Price</th>
                    <th class="price" scope="col">Quantity</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr><td>Backpack</td><td class="quantity">1</td><td id="back-price" class="price">56.99</td><td></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Calculator</td><td class="quantity">1</td><td id="calc-price" class="price">104.89</td><td></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Textbook</td><td class="quantity">1</td><td id="text-price" class="price">51.97</td><td></td></tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                  <tr><td></td><td></td><td id="sub-total" class="price"><td class="">Subtotal</td></tr>
                  <tr><td></td><td></td><td id="tax-amount" class="price"></td><td class="">Tax</td></tr>
                  <tr><td></td><td></td><td id="total" class="price total"></td><td class="total">Total Cost</td></tr>
             </tfoot>
            </table>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Gets the Prices of Items
function getBackPrice(){
    let backElement = document.getElementById("back-price") ;
    let backPrice= document.getElementById("back-price").textContent;
    return backPrice;
}


function getCalcPrice(){
    let calcElement = document.getElementById("calc-price") ;
    let calcPrice= document.getElementById("calc-price").textContent;
    return calcPrice;
}

function getTextPrice(){
    let textElement = document.getElementById("text-price") ;
    let textPrice= document.getElementById("text-price").textContent;
    return textPrice;
}


//Gets Subtotal
function getsubTotal(){
    //let subTotal = parseFloat(textPrice) + parseFloat(calcPrice) + parseFloat(backPrice);
    let subTotal = Number(getTextPrice()) + Number(getCalcPrice()) + Number(getBackPrice());
    let subTotalElement = document.getElementById("sub-total");
    subTotalElement.textContent = (subTotal);

    return subTotal;

}

//Calculate SalesTax
function calcsalesTax(subTotal) {
    const taxAmount = 0.13;
    //let salestaxElement = document.getElementById("tax-amount");
    //let salesTax = document.getElementById("tax-amount").textContent;
    //salesTax = getsubTotal() * Number(taxAmount);
    //return salesTax;

    let salesTax = getsubTotal() * Number(taxAmount);
    let salestaxElement = document.getElementById("tax-amount");
    salestaxElement.textContent = (salesTax);
    return salesTax;
}



//calculate final total cost
function calcfinalTotalCost() {
   let finalTotalCost = getsubTotal() + calcsalesTax();
   let calcfinalTotalCostElement = document.getElementById("total");
   calcfinalTotalCostElement.textContent = (finalTotalCost);

   return finalTotalCost;
}


function Output(){
    const salesTax = calcsalesTax();

    console.log('Item Subtotal = ',getsubTotal());
    console.log('Sales Tax = ',calcsalesTax());
    console.log('Total Cost = ',calcfinalTotalCost());
}

Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong in the below function

```
function getsubTotal(){
       let subTotal = parseFloat(textPrice) + parseFloat(calcPrice) + parseFloat(backPrice);
       return subTotal;

   }
```

just you should call the function instead of using the variable, because **textPrice**, **calcPrice**, **backPrice** these variables currently in local scope.

simply you can modify like this:

```
function getsubTotal(){
           let subTotal = parseFloat(getTextPrice()) + parseFloat(getCalcPrice()) + parseFloat(getBackPricea());
           return subTotal;

       }
```